# laravel 4 redirection issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a registration form and it was working until it just didn't. I am sure I did something with the code because I am new to laravel 4 so I am unable to identify my wrong doing. Now I am getting

> This webpage has a redirect loop.

This is the route file:

```
Route::get('/','MainController@index');

Route::get('/login', 'MembersController@login');

Route::get('/signup', 'MembersController@signup');

/*handled by controller to register the user that signed up*/
Route::get('/register', 'MembersController@register');

/* Handle authenticating a user when loggin in*/


Route::post('register', array(
  'uses' => 'MembersController@register',
  'as' => 'members.register'
));
```

and this is the form opening:

```
@section('content')
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'members.register')) }}    

......

{{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

and this is the validation where if there is an error, it used to redirect to the sign-up page again and show them (and it did until it broke)

```
public function register()
    {
        $rules = array(
            # place-holder for validation rules
            'firstname' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:40|Alpha',
            'lastname' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:40|Alpha',
            'email'     => 'Required|Between:3,64|Email|Unique:users',
            'country'       => 'Required',
            'password'  =>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:7,15|Confirmed',
            'password_confirmation'=>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:7,15'

        );

        /*Create new user if no user with entered email exists. Use validator to ensure all fields are completed*/
        $user = new User;

        $validator = $this->validate(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {

            return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);

        }else{
            echo "Success";
        }

    }
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Change the following line

```
return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
```

**with this**

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

You are calling the route register infinite times.

Remove this route as well. You only need post route.

```
/*handled by controller to register the user that signed up*/
Route::get('/register', 'MembersController@register');
```

Comment: Thanks Anam for the help. Will try it out